# How to set reset_timestamps with FFMPEG C/C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I save my RTSP stream to mp4 video file every minute. But the problem is when new video created, the start time is not close to 0, it increases continously, here's out put of a video like that with ffprobe:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './2017/8/15/8/56/56.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
Duration: 00:01:00.28, start: 60.247005, bitrate: 2244 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2243 kb/s, 14.91 fps, 25 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

You can see the start value is 60.247005. When I use ffmpeg command line and add option 'reset_timestamps' it work, all start value close to 0, and if i remove 'reset_timestamps' it output videos like my code..Here's command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://usr:pass@ipaddress/Streaming/Channels/1?tcp -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_format mp4 -reset_timestamps 1 "capture-%03d.mp4"
```

So, I hope i can set the option reset_timestamps in my code, but it seem i can't. I try with this but no luck:

```
AVDictionary* opts = NULL;
av_dict_set(&opts, "reset_timestamps", "1", 0);

avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, &opts);
```

Code was posted in my previous question: [How to set start time of video saved from RTSP stream with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666743/how-to-set-start-time-of-video-saved-from-rtsp-stream-with-ffmpeg)

Anyone knows how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: How do u create that `ofmt_ctx`? IMHO, this should be a `segment_muxer` here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the ofmt_ctx is AVFormatContext. Code is post in my previous question, Could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666743/how-to-set-start-time-of-video-saved-from-rtsp-stream-with-ffmpeg

Comment: See. I mean there should be another `segment_muxer` AVFormatContext, not the one wrapping final file outcome, because `reset_timestamps` is an option of `segment muxer` AVOutputFormat. (libavformat/segment.c)  But sorry I can't give you an example since I have no experience using it.